# Why am I getting this error when I run my Discord Bot? - code: 50035

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I run my Discord bot, which is made through the Discord.js and Node.js framework, I receive the following error.

```
node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
options[0].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "string" is not int.
options[1].type[NUMBER_TYPE_COERCE]: Value "string" is not int.
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (D:\Programming\GitHub\void-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (D:\Programming\GitHub\void-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (D:\Programming\GitHub\void-bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.create (D:\Programming\GitHub\void-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:144:18) {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      options: {
        '0': { type: { _errors: [Array] } },
        '1': { type: { _errors: [Array] } }
      }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1016623217399570512/guilds/915541815225118740/commands',
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: {
      name: 'poll',
      name_localizations: undefined,
      description: 'Sets up a poll.',
      description_localizations: undefined,
      type: undefined,
      options: [
        {
          type: 'string',
          name: 'title',
          name_localizations: undefined,
          name_localized: undefined,
          description: 'The title of the poll.',
          description_localizations: undefined,
          description_localized: undefined,
          required: true,
          autocomplete: undefined,
          choices: undefined,
          options: undefined,
          channel_types: undefined,
          min_value: undefined,
          max_value: undefined,
          min_length: undefined,
          max_length: undefined
        },
        {
          type: 'string',
          name: 'content',
          name_localizations: undefined,
          name_localized: undefined,
          description: 'The content of the poll.',
          description_localizations: undefined,
          description_localized: undefined,
          required: true,
          autocomplete: undefined,
          choices: undefined,
          options: undefined,
          channel_types: undefined,
          min_value: undefined,
          max_value: undefined,
          min_length: undefined,
          max_length: undefined
        }
      ],
      default_member_permissions: undefined,
      dm_permission: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

I am unsure why I am receiving this for the code below:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const PREFIX = "!";

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    const guildID = "915541815225118740";
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
    let commands;

    if (guild) {
        commands = guild.commands;
    } else {
        commands = client.application?.commands;
    }

    commands?.create({
        name: "poll",
        description: "Sets up a poll.",
        options: [
            {
                name: "title",
                description: "The title of the poll.",
                required: true,
                type: "string"
            },
            {
                name: "content",
                description: "The content of the poll.",
                required: true,
                type: "string"
            }
        ]
    });
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) {
        return;
    }

    const { commandName, options } = interaction;

    if (commandName === "poll") {
        const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x0099FF)
            .setTitle(options.get("title"))
            .addFields(
                {
                    value: options.get("content"),
                    inline: false
                },
                {
                    value: ":thumbsup: - Yes",
                    inline: true
                },
                {
                    value: ":thumbsdown: - No",
                    inline: true
                }
            )
        }


        interaction.reply(embed);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I hope someone can help me out with this. It would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now.

Thanks,
nozzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified the option type using a string literal. It should be a value of the `ApplicationCommandOptionType` enum. So instead you should be using:

```js
{
  name: "...",
  description: "...",
  required: ...
  type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.STRING
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it resulted in another error tho :(

Comment: If this solved your original error, please mark this as the answer. So other people know this worked for you

Comment: only problem is it created another around the `ApplicationCommandOptionType`

Comment: Then please provide details on the new error

Comment: Can't as the error exceeds the character count

Comment: Don't copy the entire error, just provide the essentials...your original question includes far too many details of the error and the source code

Comment: ok... well pretty much says that `ApplicationCommandOption
Type` isn't defined

Comment: Do you have a whitespace between Option and Type, if so then remove it...it's one object

Comment: turns out it was the IDE being an a**hole